# String list initialization

Tags: vb.net, string, list

I have string, in this form : `folders = "{string1;string2;string3}"`. Each string(NR) represents the name of a directory. I have another variable, root, which holds the root path of the folder which contains the items in variable "folder". How can I initialize another variable, "fullPathFolders" of type List (Of String) with the values from variable "folders", having the root path appended to each string in the variable "folders"?

So I want something like this:

```
fullPathFolders = {rootPath + string1, rootPath + string2,rootPath + string3}
```

And I was wondering if something like this can be done:

```
 Dim fullPathFolders As List(Of String) = From {rootPath & fullPathFolders}
```

since it seems to me that it would be faster and easier than the classic method of using the String.Split method (or its equivalent in vb) and then parsing through the list of strings and adding manually at the beginning of each string the root path.

Comment: Surely it has got to be easier to just try it and see if it works, rather than post a question on here about it. By the time you have written the question you could have had the answer

Comment: I posted it here exactly because it doesn't work and wanted to see if there is somebody out there who knows a better method of achieving something like what I asked for (which was just a small exemplification of what I want to do and again, doesn't work, hence why I posted here). Now that this is out of the way, the question still stands and I would appreciate any suggestions since I am a beginner in vb.

Comment: If you read the message carefully, I proposed a solution at the bottom of my message, which I find a bit long and hoped that there is a simpler, faster and better one out there. I thought that this is a place for learning things related to programming, not to learn how to write proper text in the english language. If you have a solution to the problem I posted here, I would happily try it and then thank you sincerely. I would appreciate if the focus fell on my problem rather than my english skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
folders = "{string1;string2;string3}"
```

is not a `List` of strings, it's a single `String`.

You probably want something like

```
Dim folders = New List(Of String) From {"string1", "string2", "string3"}
```

(If you can't change that code to use a `List` in the first place, creating a `List` out of this `string` is as easy as `folders.SubString(1, folders.Length - 2).Split(";")`.

---

Then you can create the second list with something like

```
 Dim fullPathFolders = folders.Select(Function(s) rootPath & s).ToList()
```